# System of two inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

What is the solution of the following system of inequalities?
$$x+y\le 0$$
$$x^{2}+y^{2}\le 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "the solution"? The two inequalities you gave are a pretty concise way of describing a certain semicircular region of the plane.

We could describe that as the semicircular region whose center is at the origin, diameter between the points $(-\frac{\sqrt 2}2,\frac{\sqrt 2}2)$ and $(\frac{\sqrt 2}2,-\frac{\sqrt 2}2)$, in the second, third, and fourth quadrants.

We could describe it in polar coordinates

$$0\le r\le 1,\quad \frac{3\pi}4\le\theta\le\frac{7\pi}4$$

There are also multiple parameterizations in two variables, the easiest one based on the polar coordinates just given.

We could show the region as the overlap of two regions in a graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The inequality

$$x^2+y^2\leq 1$$ represents all points inside and on the boundary of the unit disk.

The inequality

$$x+y\leq 0$$ may be rewritten as $$y\leq -x$$which represents all points on or below the line $y=-x$.

Putting these two together, the system represents half a disc.

$\hskip2in$ [image]